# Вопрос новичка про картинки в Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, swift

Делаю одно приложение для всех устройств, нарезаю картинки, например, мне нада для iPad-ов две пары картинок обычные и 2x, могу я просто 2x вставить дабы уменьшить вес приложения и чем это грозит?

Answer (score 2):

Вес приложения не на много увеличится! Apple пропустит, если не будет @2x. 
Если есть однотонные картинки для кнопок или заднего фона, то используйте (UIColor *)backgroundColor. Остальные картинки слишком маленькие чтобы сильно влиять на вес исходного приложения.
 PS: а ведь есть ещё @3x ...

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете добавить только x2, поскольку iPad 2 поддерживает все последние версии iOS, но не имеет retina экрана. 
Чтобы уменьшить вес приложения используйте **slicing**. В xcassets добавляйте картинки минимального размера как для x1 так и для x2, если их уместно будет растягивать по ширине, длине или обоим измерениям. 
Далее выбираем картинки и жмем show slicing - выставляем неизменяемые бордеры и места, где картинка должна растягиваться. Таким образом можно вместо, скажем, картинки 100x500 использовать картинку 10х10.

Также используйте **vectorized pdf** - чтобы использовать одну картинку для всех возможных устройств. Вот подробное пособие как это сделать: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

Tакие картинки также поддерживают slicing

Answer (score 1):

могу ошибаться но есть риск: что приложение не удастся отправить на сервер из xcode; его не примут при рассмотрении если оно не корректно отражается на разных разрешениях